# Condiçao entre dois arrays para calendario

Tags: javascript

Tenho dois arrays meses e dias.

```
var meses = new Array("Janeiro","Fevereiro","Marco","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Septembro","Outubre","Novembro","Dezembro");


 var dias= new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
```

Queria fazer uma condiçao para que por exemplo a posicao 1 (fevereiro) fosse atribuida a posicao 1 do outro array para depois imprimir numa tabela.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var meses = {
    Janeiro : "31",
    Fevereiro : "28",
    Marco :"31",
    Abril : "30",
    Maio : "31",
    Junho : "31",
    Julho : "30",
    Agosto : "31",
    Septembro : "30",
    Outubre : "31",
    Novembro : "30",
    Dezembro : "30"};
```

Para consultar basta: console.log(meses['Janeiro']).
Melhor associar assim para evitar mais processamento.

Imprimir:

```
<script>
var txt = "";
var meses = {
    Janeiro : "31",
    Fevereiro : "28",
    Marco :"31",
    Abril : "30",
    Maio : "31",
    Junho : "31",
    Julho : "30",
    Agosto : "31",
    Septembro : "30",
    Outubre : "31",
    Novembro : "30",
    Dezembro : "30"};
var x;
for (x in meses) {
    txt += meses[x] + " ";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: certo, e agora imprimir uma tabela para casa mes?

Comment: console.log(meses['Janeiro'])

Comment: sim, mas isto mostra me so 31. Queria mostar todos  os dias, com os respetivos dias de semana.

Comment: Você quer imprimir tipo Janeiro: todos os dias ate o fim do mes e assim sucessivamente?

Comment: sim exactamente isso, imprimir Janeiro, com os seus 31 dias, e dps os outros meses. E mostrar segunda, terca, ...

Comment: você quer fazer isso em qual linguagem?

Comment: linguagem JavaScript

Comment: acesse esse link: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/combo-calendario-em-javascript